# Lock and unlock database access - database is locked

Tags: python, sqlite

I have three programs running, one of which iterates over a table in my database non-stop (over and over again in a loop), just reading from it, using a `SELECT` statement.

The other programs have a line where they insert a row into the table and a line where they delete it. The problem is, that I often get an error `sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked`.

I'm trying to find a solution but I don't understand the exact source of the problem (is reading and writing in the same time what make this error occur? or the writing and deleting? maybe both aren't supposed to work).

Either way, I'm looking for a solution. If it were a single program, I could match the database I/O with mutexes and other multithreading tools, but it's not. How can I wait until the database is unlocked for reading/writing/deleting without using too much CPU?

Comment: Which of the three is giving the error? BTW, deletion is writing, too.

Comment: Why are you using SQLite for this? It's not really designed to have multiple things accessing it simultaneously.

Comment: @jonrsharpe My system was built on SQLite and now I need to update it to have this feature, which I didn't know I'll need. At this stage of the project, moving to something like MySQL is not sensible.

Comment: No, leaving it on a platform that your actual requirements have demonstrably outgrown is not sensible. SQLite may have been the best choice at the time, but now you will have to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

you need to switch databases..

I would use the following:
postgresql as my database 
psycopg2 as the driver

the syntax is fairly similar to SQLite and the migration shouldn't be too hard for you